# "Self-Learner" badge can be earned multiple times?

Tags: discussion, badges, self-answer

The description of this badge is: "Answered your own question with score of 3 or more".

It seems that this badge can be earned multiple times, but when I examined many users who have earned it, I found no one had earned it multiple times.

Why doesn't Stack Overflow describe it as "First answered your own question with score of 3 or more"?

Comment: Because badges that can be earned multiple times have 'this badge can be earned multiple times' stated explicitly in their description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Self-Learner**

1. bronze; awarded once
2. Provide an answer to your own question that receives a score of three

this is the information from [this post on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#68258)